# Hasura: Complete transaction after successful file upload

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, hasura

I have a file uploader using **`Hasura`** and **`AWS S3`**. Is there a way for me to upload a file and insert into the database, and if one of the operations fail, rollback the change?

Here is some pseudocode to demonstrate what I mean:

```
query('... hasura query string ...').then(err => {
  if (!err) {
    s3.upload('my file').then(upload_err => {
      if (!upload_err) {
        // Commit database changes
      } else {
        // Rollback database changes
      }
    })
  }
})
```

The only thing I can think of for doing this, is capture the insert id, then delete the record if the file upload fails. This doesn't seem like a good approach though.

Comment: We first upload to blob storage (Azure in our case) and only then call mutation in hasura. I suppose that you need some kind of `id` returned by hasura? If so:  "then delete the record if the file upload fails. This doesn't seem like a good approach though." - I see nothing wrong with approach

Comment: If you have a way of sending some unique ID as metadata (or use the key) you can have a field 'upload_complete' or something and mark it true in a s3 lambda trigger. That won't delete the record on fail, but it will give a way to query the completed ones only...